# Shell script to copy and paste a particular file from one directory to another?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

As part of a Windows software project I'm working on I need to copy and paste a particular DLL file from directory A to directory B. In the process, I need to overwrite any previous version of this file in directory B.

Directory A is: Documents/Visual Studio/2015/Project/MyProject/MyProject/bin/Debug

Directory B is: This PC/Windows(C:)/Users/Public/Public Documents/B

Is there a shell script that can perform this operation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why the downvote? Would appreciate constructive criticism if there's an issue with my question :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, the reason could be you are looking for answers in the wrong place. You are looking for _batch_ programming under Windows environment but you have tagged it under _bash_ which involves a set of tools for development under Linux. Edit the question to include appropriate tags.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Inian! I've edited the question to include the appropriate tags. If you could upvote this so that it gets some visibility with the new tags I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: I guess you have been down-voted due to lack of own research, because basically you are asking other people to search the right command or to write an appropriate script for you; this is at least the reason why I down-voted your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Described goal can be achieved by single cmd command:

```
copy /Y "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio\2015\Project\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\libName.dll" "C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\B"
```

So you can put this command into `scriptName.bat` file and execute. Put `pause` at the end of the file to prevent window closing if you want to check script output.